# download only packages cannot be authenticated when offline

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, authentication

we're using 14.04.4 to make installation vm images available to our consumers.

The first part of our process is to make a vmware image that comes with the downloaded packages for offline installation. We pass a list of package names to be installed to:

```
cat /tmp/trusty-installed.list | xargs sudo apt-get --download-only --assume-yes install
```

this downloads from the mirrors we maintain. It places all the debs in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. We  do this because we'd like to make the images that we distribute available for offline installations, we don't just install them at this point as we'd like to  keep the size of images down.

later on when these images come to be provisioned we attempt to install some of these packages whilst offline;

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-zmq
```

this fails with the error;

```
WARNING: the following packages could not be authenticated!
  libpgm-5.1-0 libzmq3 python-zmq 
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

Is this expected, is there a better way to perform a download only then offline installation without a --force-yes?

Comment: Since the package  lists used by your offline `apt-get` is different from the other system, this is expected. Maybe try http://askubuntu.com/a/72270/158442

Comment: I guess there is no way to ensure the validity of the packages after they've been downloaded, after a deb is placed in the archives folder it could be manipulated breaking the security model.